# Creating Medalist MySQL view from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I need a help to create a view in MySQL.

I have a table in the name of competitions like below:

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|id| name |rank1|rank2|rank3| 
+--+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 1| cmpt1| 4   | 3   | 9   |
| 2| cmpt2| 3   | 7   | 8   |
| 3| cmpt3| 4   | 1   | 2   |
| 4| cmpt4| 5   | 8   | 4   |
| 5| cmpt5| 9   | 3   | 2   |
| 6| cmpt6| 1   | 8   | 2   |
+--+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

the rank1,2,3 values refer to the player id who has such rank at the end of that competition.

Now I want to create a MySQL view to show each player's total medals. Rank 1, 2, and 3 received gold, silver, and bronze medal respectively.

The output of the view will be like following table:

```
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|player| gold_medals|silver_medals|bronze_medals| 
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1    |     4      |     7       |     1       |
| 2    |     7      |     0       |     9       |
| 3    |     1      |     4       |     6       |
| 4    |     0      |     2       |     8       |
| 5    |     2      |     8       |     0       |
| 6    |     3      |     1       |     1       |
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why aren't player 7,8,9 in your desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have another table for list players :

> ```
> select p.playerid 
>  , count(case when playerid = rank1 then 1 end) gold_medals
>  , count(case when playerid = rank2 then 1 end) silver_medals
>  , count(case when playerid = rank3 then 1 end) bronze_medals
> from 
> players p 
> left join ranks r
> on p.playerid in (rank1, rank2, rank3)
> group by p.playerid
> ```
>
> ```
> playerid | gold_medals | silver_medals | bronze_medals
> -------: | ----------: | ------------: | ------------:
>        1 |           1 |             1 |             0
>        2 |           0 |             0 |             3
>        3 |           1 |             2 |             0
>        4 |           2 |             0 |             1
>        5 |           1 |             0 |             0
>        6 |           0 |             0 |             0
>        7 |           0 |             1 |             0
>        8 |           0 |             2 |             1
>        9 |           1 |             0 |             1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4a88daf0ae20646b2c14685e0164cca)*

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot and aggregate:

```
select playerid,
       sum(ranking = 1) as num_gold,
       sum(ranking = 2) as num_silver,
       sum(ranking = 3) as num_bronze
from ((select rank1 as playerid, 1 as ranking
       from ranks
      ) union all
      (select rank2, 2 as ranking
       from ranks
      ) union all
      (select rank3, 3 as ranking
       from ranks
      ) 
     ) p
group by playerid;
```

Note:  This only includes players who have a ranking.  Your question doesn't include a source of all players, so that seems sufficient.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d843c9f1ef4577b562bef4ba266a079) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that older versions of MySQL (pre-5.7 I think) don't support subqueries in the `FROM` clause of views.  Happily that restriction is no longer in force.